# VSTS with IIS Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am planning to automate my old IIS application with VSTS, but i could find an appropriate msbuild command that actually deploys to the IIS server. I tried the solution [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1184858/Deploying-a-Web-App-from-a-Command-Line-using-MSBu). But all in vain, it builds properly but the assembly is not published to IIS web folder. Is there any task that is specifically build for iis deploy. I have multiple CI/CD pipeline which uses MSBuild tasks, which publishes the assembly using publish profile, those works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you already tried [*IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM*](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.)? We're using this VSTS Extension since a few month and it's working flawlessly.

Overview taken from the Visual Studio Marketplace:

- Create a new website or update an existing website using AppCmd.exe.
- Create a new application pool or update an existing application pool
  using AppCmd.exe. Deploy a Web Application to the IIS Server using
- Web Deploy. Deploy a SQL Server Database using DACPAC and
  SqlPackage.exe.

Update

---

Checkout the brand new documentation Deploy to IIS web server on Windows [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups#comments-container)

Comment: is your iis server local in network or in public, looks like enabling WinRM firewall giving some public/private error

Comment: The Azure Virtual Machine is set to public profile. It's runnning inside it's own VLAN. The VM's local firewall and Azure Network Security Group (NSG) both allow the WinRM Port. Maybe this article can shed some light -> http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/fixing-winrm-firewall-exception-rule-not-working-when-internet-connection-type-is-set-to-public

Answer (score 1):

Using IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM tasks (Chris said). Sample tasks:

1. NuGet Installer task
2. Visual Studio Build task (MSBuild Arguments: `/p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true  /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\web.zip"`)
3. WinRM-IIS Web App Deployment task (Web Deploy Package: `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\web.zip`)

You can publish deployed files to server through Publish build Artifacts task, then link build to release and deploy web package to IIS in release (move step 3 to release)